# Why does my defined function not accept an array as an input?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

I am working with a double integral, and the inner integral has variable bounds. I wrote a function, using SciPy's quad integration, that allows me to evaluate this integral. However, what I want is to just evaluate the inner integral, so that all I am left with is a single, non-evaluated integral with respect to some variable. I want to then plot this "half-way" evaluated double integral vs. a range of that variable so that I can see some trend. However, when I input an array of that variable (it is just 0-10000 but increments of 1, it provides the following error message:

"ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

I have defined functions before that allow me to input an array (which outputs that function at however many points were in the array), so I am unsure as to why this message is popping up now. I think it has something to do with me using SciPy's "quad" integration when defining the function. How do I go around this so that I can input an array?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#This is the array of values of the variable I ultimately want to have the function plotted 
against
timearray = np.arange(0,10000,1)

#This below defines the general function, that is with respect to two variables (p and t)
def thomtest(p,t):
    d = 3.086e22
    c = 2.998e10
    return (3*((np.cos(p + (2*t/(d*p))))**2))/(8*(t+((p**2)*d/(2*c))))


#The function below evaluates just the inner-integral
def phib(t):
    d = 3.086e22
    c = 2.998e10
    return quad(thomtest,0.00001*(c*t)/d,np.pi, args=(t))[0]


#This evaluates the outer-integral, giving me the complete numerical answer
doubleintegral = quad(phib,0,((3.086e22)/(2.998e10)))


#This below is what gives me the error message: "ValueError: The truth 
#value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
#Use a.any() or a.all()". Apparently I cannot input an array
print(phib(timearray))
```

[Attached is a picture of the full error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBYi7.png)

Comment: A full traceback would help!  Keep in mind that `quad` evaluates a scalar integral.  It will fail, in one or other, if you provide a range of end points, or if the function returns an array.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you! Is there anything more I can add to describe my situation better? In regards to your comment, is there anyway around this so that I can input an array and get the function to be evaluated at each of those array points (python is a fairly new language to me)?

Comment: @hpaulj Also, I just attached a screenshot of the full Traceback message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [2]: doubleintegral                                                                                               
Out[2]: (0.9892936902920587, 1.3643899787751934e-08)
In [3]: phib(0)                                                                                                      
Out[3]: 6.377997354641736e-10
In [4]: phib(np.arange(0,5))                                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-89b7b858c2f5> in <module>
----> 1 phib(np.arange(0,5))

<ipython-input-1-4c64e69e4f62> in phib(t)
     10     d = 3.086e22
     11     c = 2.998e10
---> 12     return quad(thomtest,0.00001*(c*t)/d,np.pi, args=(t))[0]
     13 
     14 doubleintegral = quad(phib,0,((3.086e22)/(2.998e10)))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    336 
    337     # check the limits of integration: \int_a^b, expect a < b
--> 338     flip, a, b = b < a, min(a, b), max(a, b)
    339 
    340     if weight is None:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
In [5]:
```

The error comes when it test the integration bounds, making sure that the first is smaller than the second.

But with an array `t`, that test is multivalued, and cannot be used:

```
In [6]: d = 3.086e22  
   ...: c = 2.998e10                                                                                                 
In [7]: 0.00001*(c*np.arange(5))/d                                                                                   
Out[7]: 
array([0.00000000e+00, 9.71484122e-18, 1.94296824e-17, 2.91445237e-17,
       3.88593649e-17])
```

With `quad` you have to run your code, `phib` and `doubleintegral` once for each element of `t`.   In `numpy` we try to avoid iterations, but `quad` only works with scalar bounds.  So good old iteration is required.

Comment: Thank you very much! So essentially I would need to implement some For-loop that would allow me to evaluate the integral at each point of my array?